# Finding the best fit between Ansys model results and measurd values to optimize the parameters

Tags: finite-element-method, vibration

I have the final element model of an experimental rig respresenting a vibrating system. The time domain results from both are known. I need to reduce the error between the results/find the best fit model. I also need to find the optimum paramters (namely stiffness, damping etc.) leading to the least error solution. Optimisation methods like LSM and PSO cannot be implemented efficiently as the exact simulation function cannot be extracted from ansys. It seems mostly this is done by conducting multiple simulations for ranges of input parameters and then comparing the results. Is there any other way by which this can be done? What would be the ideal way to compare the results from both?

Comment: What measurement errors are possible on the equipment? how will this affect the results? What simulation functions are used? If you don't know then how can you expect to evaluate them?

Comment: I guess my question was not clear. I am trying to create a model that represents the experimental rig. My aim is to study how efficiently can my model represent the real rig.  I have used the same input parameters as in the experiment, however the simulation results are obviously not the same as that of the experimental results. I am trying to calibrate the model parameters so that the error between the experimental results and the model results are reduced.

Comment: So what measurement errors do you have when measuring your real rig? How will those affect any results?

Comment: What I mean by error here is the difference between the model results and experimental results. I am supposed to keep the experimental results as a benchmark. I need to update my model so that the results reach as close as possible to the experimental values.

Comment: For analytical model we can use least square minimization or similar algorithms to minimize the error between the model and exp value. But this requires a functional relationship that defines the model, which is difficult to have in an ansys analysis.